# using socket.io with dojo MultipleDefine error

Tags: javascript, web, dojo, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to develop a web app. I already have working code where socket.io is used to communicate between the server side and client side.

Now, I want to write the interface using Dojo, but the two won't play nicely together
Here is what I have:

```
<script src="dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async:true, parseOnLoad:true"></script>    
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane"]);
</script>
```

The error I get:

```
Error {src: "dojoLoader", info: Object}
get stack: function () { [native code] }
info: Object
message: "multipleDefine"
set stack: function () { [native code] }
src: "dojoLoader"
__proto__: d
 dojo.js:1849
```

If I comment out this line: `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`
Dojo works correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load socket.io using the AMD loader instead of injecting the script yourself, as it is an AMD module.

```
require([ 'socket.io/socket.io' ], …);
```

Comment: this helped me for loading moment.js with dojo :)

Answer (score 0):

even better - you don't need socket.io.js - you would just need dojo

```
"dojox/socket"
```

https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2012/11/05/dojo-websocket-with-amd/